# addEventListeners overwrites other EventListeners

Tags: addeventlistener

I'm writing a script that will create an additional button 'heart' to copy link to clipboard.

```js
var AllReferenceNode = document.getElementsByClassName('rowid-link');
for (var i = 0; i < AllReferenceNode.length; i++) {
    var XnewNode = document.createElement('a');
    XnewNode.innerHTML = "<span class='icon fa fa-heart'></span>";
    XnewNode.id = AllReferenceNode[i].getAttribute("href");
    XnewNode.className = "QKCopyLink";
    XnewNode.href = "javascript:void(0);";
    AllReferenceNode[i].after(XnewNode);
}
var Links = document.getElementsByClassName('QKCopyLink');
for (var i = 0; i < Links.length; i++) {
  //console.log(i);
  var href = document.getElementsByClassName('rowid-link')[i].getAttribute("href");
  //console.log(dupa);
  //console.log(document.getElementById(dupa));
  document.getElementById(href).addEventListener('click', function(){
     var dummy = document.createElement('input');
     //var copyText = document.getElementsByClassName("rowid-link").getAttribute("href");
     document.body.appendChild(dummy);
     dummy.value = href;
     dummy.select();
     document.execCommand('copy');
     document.body.removeChild(dummy);
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<h6 class="history-title">Sat, 2019-11-16, 03:52

  | Notes

  |
  <span class="username">USER</span>&nbsp;
  <a href="#1-2LS7J5O" class="rowid-link">
    <span class="icon bookmark fa fa-cloud"></span></a>

  <span class="history-reply">

    [<a href="#" class="activity-reply">reply</a>]
  </span>

</h6>

<h6 class="history-title">Sat, 2019-11-16, 03:52

  | Notes

  |
  <span class="username">USER</span>&nbsp;
  <a href="#1-2LS7v5O" class="rowid-link">
    <span class="icon bookmark fa fa-cloud"></span></a>

  <span class="history-reply">

    [<a href="#" class="activity-reply">reply</a>]
  </span>

</h6>


<h6 class="history-title">Sat, 2019-11-16, 03:52

  | Notes

  |
  <span class="username">USER</span>&nbsp;
  <a href="#1-2LS7JdO" class="rowid-link">
    <span class="icon bookmark fa fa-cloud"></span></a>

  <span class="history-reply">

    [<a href="#" class="activity-reply">reply</a>]
  </span>

</h6>


<h6 class="history-title">Sat, 2019-11-16, 03:52

  | Notes

  |
  <span class="username">USER</span>&nbsp;
  <a href="#1-2LS7JaO" class="rowid-link">
    <span class="icon bookmark fa fa-cloud"></span></a>

  <span class="history-reply">

    [<a href="#" class="activity-reply">reply</a>]
  </span>

</h6>
```

The problem is that last run of the loop overwrites all events - all "hearts" copy the same link which is the last one. It looks like events are overwriten, but not sure how's this possible since I point element on which event listener should be set:

`document.getElementById(href).addEventListener('click', function(){...`

Please explain me why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

`dummy.value = href;`

to this:

`dummy.value = this.id;`

Fixed the issue.